# how store gradient color code in a string variable of JSP

Tags: css, jsp

i generated a graph using CSS and JSP code by fetching values from a python algorithm. Anyway, i gave green color to the  generated graph.

```
<% String GREEN_COLOR="#4DC65C"; %>
<% String isnt_graph_color_code=GREEN_COLOR; %>
```

This works perfect and generates my graph with green color.

Now the problem is that i want to generate my graph by using the following gradient color.

```
background: linear-gradient(-180deg, #4AEC74 4%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.32) 100%);
```

I tried:

```
<% String GREEN_COLOR = "linear-gradient(-180deg, #4AEC74 4%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.32) 100%);" %>
<% String isnt_graph_color_code=GREEN_COLOR; %>
```

but it didn't work out. Please Help Me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because `<% String isnt_graph_color_code=GREEN_COLOR; %>` expects a **color-code not an image** (which is returned by `linear-gradient`).

**`linear-gradient(-180deg, #4AEC74 4%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.32) 100%);` returns a `background-image` not a `background-color`.**

`background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #4AEC74 4%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.32) 100%);` works.

But `background-color: linear-gradient(-180deg, #4AEC74 4%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.32) 100%);` doesn't.

**You fix this by using: `background:` instead of `background-color:` in your CSS.**

Both

```
background: linear-gradient(-180deg, #4AEC74 4%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.32) 100%);
```

AND

```
background: #CCC555;
```

would work.

Comment: background: linear-gradient(-180deg, #4AEC74 4%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.32) 100%); works in css.. But how can i color my graph ? i mean i cant use background property but i can only use color property in my graph displaying code

Comment: Just set the background as the linear gradient. Don't use background color property. If thats not possible, use transparent background in your graph & have a div with background behind it.